# Powershell function returns stdout? (Old title: Powershell append to array of arrays appends stdout?)

Tags: powershell, return, stdout, return-value

I've learnt from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157179/append-an-array-to-an-array-of-arrays-in-powershell) how to append to an array of arrays. However, I've observed the weirdest behaviour ever. It seems to append stdout too! Suppose I want to append to an array of arrays, but I want to echo debug messages in the loop. Consider the following function.

```
function WTF {
  $Result = @()
  $A = 1,2
  $B = 11,22
  $A,$B | % {
    Write-Output "Appending..."
    $Result += , $_
  }
  return $Result
}
```

Now if you do `$Thing = WTF`, you might think you get a `$Thing` that is an array of two arrays: `$(1,2)` and `$(11,22)`. But that's not the case. If you type `$Thing` in the terminal, you actually get:

```
Appending...
Appending...
1
2
11
22
```

That is, `$Thing[0]` is the string "Appending...", `$Thing[1]` is the string "Appending...", `$Thing[2]` is the array `@(1,2)`, and `$Thing[3]` is the array `@(11,22)`. Nevermind that they seem to be in a weird order, which is a whole other can of worms I don't want to get into, but why  does the echoed string "Appending..." get appended to the result??? This is so extremely weird. How do I stop it from doing that?

**EDIT**

Oh wait, upon further experimenting, the following simpler function might be more revealing:

```
function WTF {
  $Result = @()
  1,2 | % {
    Write-Output "LOL"
  }
  return $Result
```

Now if you do `$Thing = WTF`, then `$Thing` becomes an array of length 2, containing the string "LOL" twice. Clearly there is something fundamental about Powershell loops and or `Write-Output` that I'm not understanding.

**ANOTHER EDIT!!!**

In fact, the following even simpler function does the same thing:

```
function WTF {
  1,2 | % {
    Write-Output "LOL"
  }
}
```

Maybe I just shouldn't be using `Write-Output`, but should use `Write-Information` or `Write-Debug` instead.

Comment: `return ,$Result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- PowerShell doesn't have *return values*, it has a *success output stream* (the analog of *stdout* in traditional shells).

  - The PowerShell [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) serves as the conduit for this stream, both when capturing command output in a variable and when sending it to another command via `|`, the [pipeline *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-)
- Any statement - including *multiple* ones, possibly in a *loop* - inside a function or script can write to that stream, typically *implicitly* - by not capturing, suppressing, or redirecting output - or *explicitly*, with [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), although its use is rarely needed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) for more information.

  - Output is sent *instantly* to the success output stream, as it is being produced - even before the script or function exits.
- [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) exists *for flow control*, *independently* of PowerShell's output behavior; as *syntactic sugar* you *may* also use it to write to the output stream; that is, `return $Result` is syntactic sugar for: `$Result; return`, with `$Result` by itself producing implicit output, and `return` exiting the scope.
- To avoid polluting the *success* output stream - intended for *data* output only - with status messages, write to one of the *other* available output streams - see the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic.

  - [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) is a good choice, because it is silent by default, and can be activated on demand, either via [`$VerbosePreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#verbosepreference)  `= 'Continue'`, or, on a per-call basis, with the [common `-Verbose` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-verbose), assuming the script or function is an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one.
  - [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), by contrast, *unconditionally* prints information to the host (display), and allows control over formatting, notably coloring.
- Outputting a *collection* (array) from a script or function *enumerates* it. That is, instead of sending the collection *itself*, as a whole, *its elements* are sent to PowerShell's pipeline, *one by one*, a process called *streaming*.

  - PowerShell commands generally expect streaming output, and may not behave as expected if you output a collection *as a whole*.
  - When you do want to output a collection as a whole (which may sometimes be necessary for performance reasons), wrap them in a transient aux. single-element array, using the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-): `, $Result`

    - A conceptually clearer (but less efficient) alternative is to use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`
    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360724/45375) for more information.

---

Therefore, the PowerShell idiomatic reformulation of your function is:

```
function WTF {
  
  # Even though no parameters are declared,
  # these two lines are needed to activate support for the -Verbose switch,
  # which implicitly make the function an *advanced* one.
  # Even without it, you could still control verbose output via
  # the $VerbosePreference preference variable.
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()

  $A = 1,2
  $B = 11,22
  
  # Use Write-Verbose for status information.
  # It is silent by default, but if you pass -Verbose
  # on invocation or set $VerbosePreference = 'Continue', you'll 
  # see the message.
  Write-Verbose 'Appending...'

  # Construct an array containing the input arrays as elements
  # and output it, which *enumerates* it, meaning that each
  # input array is output by itself, as a whole.
  # If you need to output the nested array *as a whole*, use
  #    , ($A, $B)
  $A, $B
}
```

Sample invocation:

```
PS> $nestedArray = WTF -Verbose
VERBOSE: Appending...
```

Note:

- Only the *success* output (stream `1`) was captured in variable `$nestedArray`, whereas the *verbose* output (stream `4`) was passsed through to the display.
- `$nestedArray` ends up as an *array* - even though `$A` and `$B` were in effect streamed *separately* - because PowerShell *automatically* collects *multiple* streamed objects in an array, which is always of type `[object[]]`.
- A notable pitfall is that if there's only *one* output object, it is assigned as-is, not wrapped in an array.

  - To ensure that a command's output is is *always* an array, even in the case of single-object output:

    - You can enclose the command in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)

      ```
       $txtFiles = @(Get-ChildItem *.txt)
      ```
    - In the case of a variable assignment, you can also use a *type constraint* with `[array]` (effectively the same as `[object[]]`):

      ```
       [array] $txtFiles = Get-ChildItem *.txt
      ```
    - However, note that if a given single output object *itself* is a collection (which, as discussed, is unusual), no *extra* array wrapper is created by the commands above, and if that collection is of a type *other than an array*, it will be converted to a regular `[object[]]` array.
      Additionally, if `@(...)` is applied to a *strongly typed* array (e.g., `[int[]] (1, 2)`, it is in effect enumerated and rebuilt as an `[object[]]` array; by contrast, the `[array]` type constraint (cast) preserves such an array as-is.

---

As for your **specific observations and questions**:

> I've learnt from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6157179/45375) how to append to an array of arrays

While using `+=` in order to incrementally build an array is *convenient*, it is also *inefficient*, because a *new* array must be constructed every time - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375) for how to construct arrays efficiently, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375) for how to use an efficiently extensible *list* type as an alternative.

> Nevermind that they seem to be in a weird order, which is a whole other can of worms I don't want to get into

Output to the pipeline - whether implicit or explicit with `Write-Output` is *instantly* sent to the success output stream.

Thus, your `Write-Output` output came *first*, given that you didn't output the `$Result` array until later, via `return`.

> How do I stop it from doing that?

As discussed, don't use `Write-Output` for *status* messages.