# Microsoft Graph User Creation

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm scripting a new version of a script I've done before, but I'm upgrading it to use MSGraph for Office 365 account creation.

I'm running across an issue here, since I created a function to test if a user exists:

```
#Function to check account existence
Function AccountExists
{
    Param(
            [string]$fxEmailAccount
          )
    
    #Validamos si la cuenta existe
    $return = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean("TRUE")
    try {
        $user = Get-MgUser -UserId $fxEmailAccount
        Write-Output $($user.Count())
    }
    catch {
            $return = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean("FALSE")
    }
    return $return
}

$result = AccountExists -fxEmailAccount zpinillal@mydomain.com
```

Partially this works for me, the issue here is how can I properly check for the existence of an account, since Get-MGUser returns an object and every time I run my function, it sometimes fail because of my implemented logic.

I already tried to use Get-MgUserCount, but didnt' got any luck on this approach either.

Can someone tell me what might I'm doing wrong or not interpreting well to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can probably be reduced to the following, PowerShell-idiomatic form:

```bash
function Test-AccountExists {
  param(
    $UserId
  )
  [bool] (Get-MgUser -UserId $UserId -ErrorAction Ignore)
}

# Sample invocation
$result = Test-AccountExists -UserId zpinillal@mydomain.com
```

- The name `Test-AccountExists` uses PowerShell's verb-noun naming convention with the [approved verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) `Test`.
- `-ErrorAction Ignore` ignores an error resulting from an non-existent user ID and makes `Get-MgUser` produce no output.
- Casting to `[bool]`, using [PowerShell's to-Boolean coercion logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Booleans), yields `$true` if a user object is returned, and `$false` in the no-output case.
- Since the cast is neither captured in a variable nor sent to a different command, its result is *implicitly output*, i.e. becomes the "return value" of the function (more on that below).
- As [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) notes, what [`Get-MgUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser)'s `-UserId` parameter accepts is either a UPN (user principal name) or a GUID, and not every email address is also a UPN, so it's better to use `-UserId` as the name of the parameter of your function too.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- PowerShell has built-in constants ([automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)) for Boolean values: `$true` and `$false`, so there is no need for `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean("...")`
- I *assume* that the error that `Get-MgUser` returns when a user with the given identity doesn't exist is a *non-terminating* error: such an error is *not* caught with a [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement in PowerShell - unless you promote it to a *terminating* one with `-ErrorAction Stop`. However, in the case at hand, it's simpler to use `-ErrorAction Ignore` to *ignore* the error, and infer the existence from the absence of output, as shown above.
- > `Write-Output $($user.Count())`

  - Due to the aforementioned implicit output behavior:

    - The statement could be simplified to `$user.Count()`

      - However, it looks like the [objects returned by `Get-MgUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.powershell.cmdlets.resources.msgraph.models.apiv10.imicrosoftgraphuser?view=az-ps-latest) do *not* implement a `.Count()` *method*, so this call will likely fail - and trigger the `catch` block.
      - By contrast, any object in PowerShell is guaranteed to have a `.Count` *property*: If a given object's type doesn't have a native property by that name, PowerShell provides it as an [intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), reporting `1` for scalar (non-collection) objects and `0` for `$null`.
  - More importantly, if the statement *did* write something, it would become part of the function's "return value" (stream of output objects) *too* - not just what you pass to [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return).

    - For conceptual information about PowerShell's implicit output behavior and the role of the `return` keyword, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899230/45375)

Comment: Thanks to all pointing me in the right direction.  I make adjustments to my script and it is working as expected.  Thanks.